# How can I replace and multiply dimensions of img tags in Perl or Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, regex, perl

I have a folder full of html files created for a Kindle ebook.  The images are coded with width and height, as per the Kindle guidelines:

```
<img width="328" height="234" src="images/224p_fmt.jpeg" alt="224p.tif"/>
```

What I need to create/find is a script that will process all the image tags, multiply the width an height attributes by a specified amount (coded into the script) and write them back into the html files.

So, for the above example, say I want to multiply by 1.5, and wind up with

```
<img width="492" height="351" src="images/224p_fmt.jpeg" alt="224p.tif"/>
```

Scripts like this are not my forte, so help appreciated.  I especially am unclear on how to write a script that I can run on file(s) from the command line and just input/output html.

I assume the meat of the code would be something like

```
s/<img width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)" src="(.*?)" alt=".*"/>/'<img width="'.$1*1.5.'" height="'.$2*1.5.'" src="'.$3.'" alt=""/>'/eg;
```

Which I realize is incorrect (the multiplication part) which is why help appreciated.

Comment: Is Python okay?  Or just perl/ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python I'd do it like this.

```python
import sys, re

source = sys.stdin.read()
def multi(by):
  def handler(m):
    updated = int(m.group(2)) * by
    return m.group(1) + str(updated)
  return handler

print re.sub(r'((?:width|height)=["\'])(\d+)', multi(1.5), source)
```

Then you can handle input and output on the command like using `<` and `>`.

```
$ python resize.py < index.html > new_file.html
```

Comment: This is great, but there must be a typo in it since it leaves off the leading quote for the printout of the image width: `<img width=492.0" height=351.0" src="images/224p_fmt.jpeg" alt="224p.tif"/>`

Comment: I misplaced a parenthesis, so the quote got left out of the first subpattern.  Does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

You've already got the main regex figured out, just need to tweak it and decide a language. Using regexes on html is not optimal, but since this is somewhat straightforward, its probably ok.

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's/<img width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)"/q(<img width=") . 
    $1*1.5 . q(" height=") . $2*1.5 . q(")/eg;' yourfile.html
```

Note the use of the alternate quoting `q(...)`, since using single quotes on the command line will conflict with the shell quoting.

There's no need to touch any parts you're not changing, unless you feel the need to make a stricter match. If you do, you can add a look-ahead assertion:

```
(?=\s*src=".*?"\s*alt=".*?"\/>)
```

This part will remain unchanged by the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the [nokogiri](http://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) gem to parse the HTML, search for image tags, extract the width and height attributes and then output the changed document so you can save it.

More information at the [nokogiri tutorial page](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials).

Comment: I just installed nokogiri, seems to be installed correctly, but the various tutorials all fail.  For example, the very first:

`html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><h1>Mr. Belvedere Fan Club</h1></body></html>")`

Fails with `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it can be done with a small Ruby script. It can look like this :

```
source = '<img width="328" height="234" src="images/224p_fmt.jpeg" alt="224p.tif"/>'
datas = source.scan(/<img width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)" src="(.*?)" alt=".*">/).flatten!
source.gsub!(data[0], (data[0].to_i * 1.5).to_s)
source.gsub!(data[1], (data[1].to_i * 1.5).to_s)
```

Of course, it's a quick and dirty script, far from perfect and it has some drawback.